# JavaScript - how to run setInterval() only 1 time

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

```
<button onClick="increase = setInterval(increasing, 400);
        clearInterval(decrease);"><b>Sicaklik Arttir (+)</b>
</button>

<button onClick="clearInterval(increase);
        clearInterval(decrease);"><b>Stop</b
</button>

<button onClick="decrease = setInterval(decreasing, 400);
        clearInterval(increase)"><b>Sicaklik Azalt  (-)</b>
</button>
```

I have buttons that include `setInterval`. When I press button, `setInterval` is called, but when I press again, `setInterval` is called again, and I can't stop it.

How do I stop it?

I want to run `setInterval` only one time.

Answer (score 2):

There is setTimeout method which calls only once at a time.

```
setTimeout(increasing, 400)
```

To clear the timeout use clearTimeout method.

Comment: how can I use setTimeout? Can you expalin please

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value before button clicked 2nd time and before timeout of 400 seconds ,

```
 if(! increase)
   increase = setTimeout(increasing, 400);
```

Then clear timeout :

```
 clearTimeout(increase);
```